How do I deconstruct this function from props in React?
I am learning React and useState. I have the below code that acts as a signup function. When a username and password are POST to the API, a message returns along with a token.
import { useState } from "react";
const API_URL = '';

export default function SignUpForm() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    
    

    

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        try {
            const response = await fetch(API_URL, {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username:username,
                    password:password,
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
            
            const result = await response.json();
            console.log(result);


            //Attempting to use state function to grab token and store it. 
            setToken(result.token);
            console.log(token)

            
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error.message)
        }
        
      }

    

    return (
    <>
        <h2>Sign Up!</h2>
        {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                Username: <input value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}/> 
            </label>
            <label>
                Password: <input value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            </label>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </> 
    );
  }

I am trying to use the useState from the App.jsx file below:
const [token, setToken] = useState(null); to set the token.
import './App.css'
import SignUpForm from './components/SignUpForm'
import Authenticate from './components/Authenticate'
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      
      <SignUpForm token={token} setToken={setToken} />

      <Authenticate token={token} setToken={setToken} />

    </>
  );
}

export default App

I have been told to "deconstruct the setToken function from props." But I have no clue what this means. I'm not sure if I need to create another useState of the same type inside the current file or not. How am I supposed to deconstruct setToken?
Also, API_URL does have a value, I just took it out for security reasons.

this will work for you:
export default function SignUpForm({token, setToken}) {
  // your code 
}

here you can see detailed explanation:
https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#step-2-read-props-inside-the-child-component

You need some changes in your SignUpForm component :
 export default function SignUpForm(props){
          //deconstruct your props 
          const {token , setToken} = props
          //rest of your code 
 }

you need to learn more about props in react and reconstruction props in react . here is a link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructuring-of-props-in-reactjs/
